# ExoPlayer+CastPlayer add subtitles (closed captions) using MediaItem

Tags: android, kotlin, video, exoplayer, closed-captions

I am trying to configure both SimpleExoPlayer and CastPlayer to display subtitles on device/TV.
I create MediaItem as follows:

```
private fun createMediaItem(url: String, type: PlayerViewSourceType): MediaItem {
        val uri = Uri.parse(url)
        val mediaItemBuilder = MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri(uri)
        if (type == PlayerViewSourceType.HLS) {
            val subtitle = MediaItem.Subtitle(uri, MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT, "en", C.SELECTION_FLAG_AUTOSELECT)
            mediaItemBuilder.apply {
                setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8)
                setSubtitles(listOf(subtitle))
            }
        } else {
            val subtitle = MediaItem.Subtitle(uri, MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT, "en", C.SELECTION_FLAG_AUTOSELECT)
            mediaItemBuilder.apply {
                setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MP4)
                setSubtitles(listOf(subtitle))
            }
        }

        return mediaItemBuilder.build()
    }
```

I use same url, because subtitles are coming with video and it works this way on iOS side. Also `Subtitles` object is the same for both cases so could be created before if-else but I tried different sets of parameters so I left it as it is. It didn't work this way. Unfortunatelly `addTextOutput {}` is deprecated so I've been searching further and I found out that I can add it as `Player.Listener` implementation, so I created a class:

```
private inner class SubtitlesListener() : Player.Listener, TextOutput {
        override fun onCues(cues: MutableList<Cue>) {
            subtitleView.onCues(cues)
        }
    }
```

And with this class I added another listeners for my players:

```
playerStorage.simpleExoPlayer.addListener(SubtitlesListener())
playerStorage.castPlayer.addListener(SubtitlesListener())
```

And to zip it all together I added click listener for CC button:

```
private fun setupSubtitlesClickListener() {
        ccButton.setOnClickListener {
            when (playerStorage.isDisplayingSubtitles) {
                true -> {
                    playerStorage.showSubtitles(false)
                    ccButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_closed_caption_inactive_24_px)
                    subtitleView.gone()
                }
                else -> {
                    playerStorage.showSubtitles(true)
                    ccButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_closed_caption_white_16_px)
                    subtitleView.visible()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For now only one video in app has subtitles for testing purposes and it is `.mp4` video file. Unfortunately this solution doesn't work.
I have found plenty implementations for subtitles, but the latest is from 2020 and it is not applicable here. Also I can't use `MergingMediaSource` because CastPlayer accepts only `MediaItem`. `SimpleExoPlayer` can use it too, so I can create one type of object for both players. Even if I would use `MediaSource` just for `SimpleExoPlayer` I still couldn't add subtitles for `CastPlayer.
I can use m3u8 for all cases, so I don't need to read files from separate file.

Comment: Check out DefaultTrackSelector class of exoplayer to show captions.

Comment: Do you know maybe if I can use it when I want to attach subtitles from outside source. I have video file and subtitles flre separated.

Comment: Also looks like I can't apply it to CastPlayer which I use along with SimpleExoPlayer even if I have HLS video.